# Why this simple postgresql function call does not work?

Tags: postgresql

Even though i tried different variants and searched internet could not found a way to resolve this ?
My function call is

```
select get_byte( md5('key')::text , 0);
```

Does not work.

According to this http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html `md5` take string input and produce text while `get_byte` expect string input ( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-binarystring.html ) . What am i missing here ? Error is `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the md5 return value to `bytea`, not `text`:

```
> SELECT get_byte(MD5('key')::bytea, 0);
 get_byte
----------
       51
(1 row)
```